# php methods binded together

Tags: php, oop

I have seen in ORMS or Frameworks, that you can have methods attached together

Example,

```
$user->select('id')->where('web');
```

So, how can `where` method attached to `select` method?

Comment: It's called a "Fluent interface", and each method call returns the object itself (ie `$this`)

Comment: @MarkBaker that should be the answer.

Comment: @Jessica - I never consider it worth an answer if I can respond in a comment in fewer characters than twitter permits

Comment: please stop using active record pattern for everything

Comment: and why should it be avoided?

Comment: @meWantToLearn because it mixes domain and persistence logic. Instead you should try to implement [data mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern (no, it is not a name of an ORM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That expression is equivalent to:

```
$temp = $user->select('id');
$temp->where('web');
```

It's no different from combining multiple arithmetic operations in a mathematical expression: the result of one sub-expression is used as a parameter to the adjacent one. In this case, `select()` returns a class object that has a `where()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The method `select()` simply returns the current instance from itself. For example:

```
public function select($column)
{
    // Do some cool stuff;
    return $this;
}
```

If the object also has a method called `where()`, this is now available using the chained syntax you've indicated.